# Find the minimum value of $x^2 + y^2$ given the equation $xy−x−y=1$

Tags: calculus

$x, y \in \mathbb{R}, xy - x - y = 1,$ do you know the value of $\min(x^{2} + y^{2})$?

Could you give me the result of $\min(x^{2} + y^{2})$ and how you get the result?

This is my attempt and I got the final result:

Solution 1 (Algebra)

[image: Solution 1]

Solution 2 （Geometry）

[image: Solution 2]

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the wiki you shared.
I have my work and actually I have 2 solutions to get the final result. I wrote it down on a paper. Will post it later or try to learn how to type it and format it, thanks. @AnneBauval

Comment: That's a good question actually.  But it will be much better, if you share your efforts/attempts to solve it, and include that in the body of your question.  This way we know what you already know, so that we correct it if there are any errors, or guide you to the answer.

Comment: @HosamH thanks for your reply. I updated my attempts. Guess that there is more elegant solution or higher solution like using other methods.

Comment: @AnneBauval I updated my attempts using the picture. Will learn the latex later to better express my solution or idea.

Comment: Regarding typing and formatting, you can use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), a watered down version of TeX which is specifically designed for chat features.

Comment: @LeeMosher really appreciate your sharing.

Comment: This looks like a standard Lagrange multipliers exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to what you've done, we have the constraint

$ xy - x- y = 1 $

It is possible to separate the variables and write,

$ y (x - 1) = x + 1 $

So that

$ y = \dfrac{x+1}{x-1} $

We can express that in parametric form as follows, a point $p(t)$ on the constraint curve is given by

$ p(t) = ( t , \dfrac{t+1}{t-1} ) $

Now our function $f$ that we want to minimize is

$ f = x^2 + y^2 = p(t) \cdot p(t) $

where $ \cdot $ is the dot product.

Differentiating $f$ with respect to $t$, we get

$ \dfrac{d  f}{ d  t } = 2 p(t) \cdot p'(t) $

and we have,

$ p'(t) = (1 , \dfrac{ -2 }{(t - 1)^2}) $

Therefore,

$ \dfrac{d  f}{ d  t } = 2 ( t - 2 \dfrac{ t+1 }{(t - 1)^3 } ) = 0 $

Hence, we have to solve

$ t - 2  \dfrac{ t+1 }{(t - 1)^3 } = 0 $

Multiplying through by $(t - 1)^3$, gives us,

$ t (t - 1)^3 - 2 (t + 1) = 0 $

Expanding,

$ t (t^3 - 3 t^2 + 3 t - 1) - 2 t - 2 = 0 $

And this simplifies to,

$ t^4 - 3 t^3 + 3 t^2 - 3 t - 2 = 0 $

Using [Wolframalpha.com](https://www.wolframalpha.com/), we get the roots of this quartic equation.  The real roots are only two:

$t_1 = 1 - \sqrt{2} $

$ t_2 = 1 + \sqrt{2} $

The corresponding points $(x,y)$ are

For $t_1$ , $(x_1, y_1) = (1 - \sqrt{2}, 1- \sqrt{2}) $

For $t_2$, $ (x_2, y_2) = (1 + \sqrt{2} , 1 + \sqrt{2}) $

Clearly $x_1^2 + y_1^2 \lt x_2^2 + y_2^2 $

Hence, the minimum of $x^2 + y^2 $ is

$ f_{min} = x_1^2 + y_1^2 = 6 - 4 \sqrt{2} $

That was the algebraic approach.

Geometrically, the problem is much easier if you plot the function

$ y = \dfrac{x+1}{x-1} $

Because this is

$ y = \dfrac{x - 1 + 2 }{x-1} = 1 + \dfrac{2}{x-1} $

which has a well-known shape, it is the same as the function

$ g(x) = \dfrac{2}{x} $ but shifted by $1$ to the right and by $1$ up.

Note that the function $ y = \dfrac{2}{x}$ is symmetric about the line $y = x$.  Hence the closest points to the origin do actually lie on the line $y = x$.  With this, we solve

$ x = \dfrac{x+1}{x-1} \Longrightarrow x(x-1) = x+1 \Longrightarrow x^2 - 2 x - 1 = 0 \Longrightarrow x = 1 \pm \sqrt{2}  $

Now, from the graph also, we know that the minimum squared distance is achieved with $x = y = 1 - \sqrt{2}$, hence, the minimum is $6 - 4 \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Thanks, very clear and inspiring

Answer (score 3):

I found $6-4\sqrt2$ like you, with a method very close to your first one:

Letting $u=x-1$ and $v=y-1,$ we are looking for the minimum value of $(u+1)^2+(v+1)^2$ for $u,v$ such that $uv=2,$ i.e. the minimum value of
$$\Bbb R^*\ni u\mapsto f(u):=(u+1)^2+\left(\frac2u+1\right)^2.$$
Calculating
$$\begin{align}\frac{f'(u)}2&=u+1-\frac2{u^2}\left(\frac2u+1\right)\\
&=\frac{(u^2-2)(u^2+u+2)}{u^3},
\end{align}$$
we find that the minimum is attained either for $u=\sqrt2$ or for $u=-\sqrt2.$ Comparing the two values, we conclude that the minimum is
$$f(-\sqrt2)=2(-\sqrt2+1)^2=6-4\sqrt2.$$

Comment: Thanks, one tiny correction, the first line of the answer may be wrong?
Should be 6 - 42‾√ ?

Comment: @FrancisBacon Typo fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by Anne Bauval's change of variables, I come up with the following solution.

Note that $xy-x-y=1 \iff (x-1)(y-1)=2$

Let $u=x-1$, $v=y-1$ and $x^2+y^2=r^2$.

Then we are minimizing the value of $(u+1)^2+(v+1)^2=r^2$ subject to the constraint $uv=2.$

[image]

If we draw the hyperbola $uv=2$ and the circle  $(u+1)^2+(v+1)^2=r^2$ as shown, then to minimize $x^2+y^2$ is the same finding the smallest circle $(u+1)^2+(v+1)^2=r^2$ which cuts the hyperbola.

From the figure, the line $v=u$ cuts the hyperbola $uv=2$ at $B(-\sqrt 2, -\sqrt 2)$ and $C(\sqrt 2, \sqrt 2)$.

Minimum $r^2$ is given by
$$r^2=AB^2=(-1+\sqrt 2)^2+(-1+\sqrt 2)^2=6-4 \sqrt 2.$$

Therefore minimum $x^2+y^2=6-4 \sqrt 2.$